# Por que eu não posso acessar o dado dessa struct com o ponto, só com a seta?

Tags: c, ponteiro, struct

Aloquei essa `struct` por alocação dinâmica e só consigo acessar o dado `idade` via seta e não por ponto queria saber o por quê?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct pessoa
{
   int idade;
};

void alteraIdade(struct pessoa *l);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   struct pessoa *jose = malloc(sizeof(int));
   alteraIdade(jose);
   printf("%d\n", jose->idade);
   free(jose);
   return 0;
}


void alteraIdade(struct pessoa *l)
{
    l->idade = 90;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Porque está acessado-a através de um ponteiro, então você precisa derreferenciar o ponteiro antes de acessar o membro.

`jose` é um ponteiro para um objeto e não o objeto em si, ele é um número com o endereço. Para pegar o objeto em si tem que dizer que quer isto, usando o operador `*` e aí com o objeto pode pegar o membro dele. Então precisa fazer `(*jose).idade`. Como isso é bastante comum criaram uma sintaxe mais simples `jose->idade`, que é a mesma coisa.